How to construct a reasonable model of yellow phase FAPbI3 used for DFT calculation from experimental results?
I construct an initial model of yellow phase FAPbI3 from literature. After I viewed this structure using VESTA, it had so much duplicated H, N and C atoms.  I know that I need to delete some atoms to make it reasonable in DFT calculations. However, I do not exactly know which atoms should be deleted. Is there any good idea to identify this?
Here is my cif file:
data_yellow-FAPbI\(2)
_audit_creation_date              2024-04-02
_audit_creation_method            'Materials Studio'
_symmetry_space_group_name_H-M    'P63/MMC'
_symmetry_Int_Tables_number       194
_symmetry_cell_setting            hexagonal
loop_
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
  x,y,z
  -y,x-y,z
  -x+y,-x,z
  -x,-y,z+1/2
  y,-x+y,z+1/2
  x-y,x,z+1/2
  y,x,-z
  x-y,-y,-z
  -x,-x+y,-z
  -y,-x,-z+1/2
  -x+y,y,-z+1/2
  x,x-y,-z+1/2
  -x,-y,-z
  y,-x+y,-z
  x-y,x,-z
  x,y,-z+1/2
  -y,x-y,-z+1/2
  -x+y,-x,-z+1/2
  -y,-x,z
  -x+y,y,z
  x,x-y,z
  y,x,z+1/2
  x-y,-y,z+1/2
  -x,-x+y,z+1/2
_cell_length_a                    8.5891
_cell_length_b                    8.5892
_cell_length_c                    7.8537
_cell_angle_alpha                 90.0000
_cell_angle_beta                  90.0000
_cell_angle_gamma                 120.0000
loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
_atom_site_U_iso_or_equiv
_atom_site_adp_type
_atom_site_occupancy
N1     N     0.26120   0.64140   0.12240   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
N2     N     0.35180   0.73220   0.39140   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
C1     C     0.38890   0.71280   0.23510   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
H1     H     0.52210   0.75480   0.19990   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
H2     H     0.22610   0.69264   0.42470   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
H3     H     0.44910   0.78670   0.47740   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
H4     H     0.28950   0.62660   0.00330   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
H5     H     0.13550   0.60170   0.15570   0.06936  Uiso   0.08
Pb1    Pb    0.00000   0.00000   0.00000   0.03203  Uiso   1.00
I1     I     0.82957   0.17043   0.25000   0.05073  Uiso   1.00
loop_
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_1
_geom_bond_atom_site_label_2
_geom_bond_distance
_geom_bond_site_symmetry_2
_ccdc_geom_bond_type
N1     C1      1.300   .     S
N1     H4      0.990   .     S
N1     H5      0.991   .     S
N1     C1      0.925   2_665 S
N1     N1      0.943   3_565 S
N1     N1      0.943   2_665 S
N1     C1      1.132   3_565 S
N1     H4      1.125   3_565 S
N1     C1      1.195   10_665 S
N1     H2      1.067   10_665 S
N1     N2      0.933   11    S
N1     C1      1.260   11    S
N1     C1      1.489   12_565 S
N1     C1      1.469   16    S
N1     H2      0.744   16    S
N1     C1      1.151   17_665 S
N1     H3      0.944   17_665 S
N1     N2      1.002   18_565 S
N1     C1      1.323   18_565 S
N1     C1      0.979   19_665 S
N1     H4      1.259   19_665 S
N1     N1      1.022   20    S
N1     C1      1.058   20    S
N1     H1      1.272   20    S
N1     H4      1.183   20    S
N1     C1      1.322   21_565 S
N1     H4      0.961   21_565 S
N1     H5      1.044   21_565 S
N1     H3      1.033   10_665 S
N1     N2      0.893   12_565 S
N1     H2      0.899   12_565 S
N1     H2      1.233   17_665 S
N2     C1      1.300   .     S
N2     H2      0.991   .     S
N2     H3      0.991   .     S
N2     N1      0.933   11    S
N2     N1      1.002   17_665 S
N2     N1      0.893   12_565 S
N2     C1      1.334   2_665 S
N2     H3      1.232   2_665 S
N2     C1      1.548   3_565 S
N2     H2      0.903   3_565 S
N2     C1      1.342   10_665 S
N2     H5      1.065   10_665 S
N2     C1      1.016   11    S
N2     C1      1.214   12_565 S
N2     C1      1.081   16    S
N2     C1      1.122   17_665 S
N2     C1      1.370   18_565 S
N2     H5      1.130   18_565 S
N2     C1      1.523   19_665 S
N2     H2      0.692   19_665 S
N2     C1      1.246   20    S
N2     H2      1.221   20    S
N2     H3      0.864   20    S
N2     C1      1.412   21_565 S
N2     N2      0.967   21_565 S
N2     H4      0.888   10_665 S
N2     H4      1.187   11    S
N2     H4      1.003   12_565 S
N2     H4      1.143   16    S
N2     H4      1.088   17_665 S
N2     H4      0.843   18_565 S
C1     H1      1.050   .     S
C1     N1      0.925   3_565 S
C1     N1      1.132   2_665 S
C1     N1      1.195   10_665 S
C1     N1      1.260   11    S
C1     N1      1.489   12_565 S
C1     N1      1.469   16    S
C1     N1      1.151   18_565 S
C1     N1      1.323   17_665 S
C1     N1      0.979   19_665 S
C1     N1      1.058   20    S
C1     N1      1.322   21_565 S
C1     N2      1.334   3_565 S
C1     N2      1.548   2_665 S
C1     N2      1.342   10_665 S
C1     N2      1.016   11    S
C1     N2      1.214   12_565 S
C1     N2      1.081   16    S
C1     N2      1.122   18_565 S
C1     N2      1.370   17_665 S
C1     N2      1.523   19_665 S
C1     N2      1.246   20    S
C1     N2      1.412   21_565 S
C1     H5      1.289   3_565 S
C1     H1      1.119   12_565 S
C1     H1      1.134   16    S
C1     H1      1.034   21_565 S
H1     N1      1.272   20    S
H1     C1      1.119   12_565 S
H1     C1      1.134   16    S
H1     C1      1.034   21_565 S
H1     H1      0.794   12_565 S
H1     H1      0.794   12_565 S
H1     H1      0.787   16    S
H2     N1      1.067   10_665 S
H2     N1      0.744   16    S
H2     N1      0.899   12_565 S
H2     N1      1.233   18_565 S
H2     N2      0.903   2_665 S
H2     N2      0.692   19_665 S
H2     N2      1.221   20    S
H2     H3      0.471   2_665 S
H2     H2      0.698   19_665 S
H3     N1      0.944   18_565 S
H3     N1      1.033   10_665 S
H3     N2      1.232   3_565 S
H3     N2      0.864   20    S
H3     H2      0.471   3_565 S
H3     H4      0.670   10_665 S
H4     N1      1.125   2_665 S
H4     N1      1.259   19_665 S
H4     N1      1.183   20    S
H4     N1      0.961   21_565 S
H4     N2      0.888   10_665 S
H4     N2      1.187   11    S
H4     N2      1.003   12_565 S
H4     N2      1.143   16    S
H4     N2      1.088   18_565 S
H4     N2      0.843   17_665 S
H4     H3      0.670   10_665 S
H4     H4      0.626   2_665 S
H4     H4      0.626   3_565 S
H4     H4      0.721   19_665 S
H5     N1      1.044   21_565 S
H5     N2      1.065   10_665 S
H5     N2      1.130   17_665 S
H5     C1      1.289   2_665 S
H5     H5      0.583   21_565 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   1_455 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   2_545 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   3_665 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   4_654 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   6_444 S
Pb1    I1      3.207   5_564 S
I1     Pb1     3.207   1_655 S
I1     Pb1     3.207   4_655 S




+1 Could you provide the file of the structure, including unit cell and atomic positions? It is hard to tell what the problem is just by looking at the visualization. As a first guess, it looks like you have atoms outside the cell, VESTA would wrap all the atoms inside the cell by default which could explain why you have such duplications.

Did you get a cif or POSCAR file from literature? I'd be surprised if atoms are actually duplicated. VESTA automatically replicates atoms like you see in the figure. You could turn that off or just try running a calculation with the input positions file. many DFT codes will issue a warning or crash if atoms are overlapping.

Hi @JaafarMehrez@Tyler Sterling, I have added cif file to my question. Such phenomenon is common in extracting structure from experiment research.
